# Alphabet increment function by index number in js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge an array of objects into a single object and on the object key, I want the alphabet letters.

I have created a function **incrementLetter** it will take the index number and from the index number it will return the alphabet, the issue is the alphabet is 26 letters if the index is 27 then I want it will return **AA** if 28 then **AB** etc.. but after 26 indexes I am getting only **AA** the function doesn't return **AB** if the index is 27 or 28.

```js
function incrementLetter(charIndex) {
  const letter = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  let value = letter.charAt(charIndex);
  let carry = 1;
  let res = "";

  for (let i = value.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let char = value.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(i);

    char += carry;

    if (char > 90) {
      char = 65;
      carry = 1;
    } else {
      carry = 0;
    }

    res = String.fromCharCode(char) + res;

    if (!carry) {
      res = value.substring(0, i) + res;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (carry) {
    res = "A" + res;
  }

  return res;
}

const dataSource =[{"column_name":"id"},{"column_name":"group_name"},{"column_name":"date_lol"},{"column_name":"aaaasdccc"},{"column_name":"created_table_at"},{"column_name":"test_bro"},{"column_name":"ddddd"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"}]


  const addKeyLetter = (data) => {
    const mapped = data.map((item, i) => ({
      [incrementLetter(i -1)]: item.column_name,
    }));
    const object = Object.assign({}, ...mapped);
   console.log(object);
  };
  addKeyLetter(dataSource);
```

Expected output

```
{
  "A": "ID",
  "B": "group_name",
  "C": "date_lol",
  "D": "aaaasdccc",
  "E": "created_table_at",
  "F": "test_bro",
  "G": "ddddd",
  "H": "ddddda",
  "I": "ddddda",
  "J": "ddddda",
  "K": "ddddda",
  "L": "ddddda",
  "M": "ddddda",
  "N": "ddddda",
  "O": "ddddda",
  "P": "ddddda",
  "Q": "ddddda",
  "R": "ddddda",
  "S": "ddddda",
  "T": "ddddda",
  "U": "ddddda",
  "V": "ddddda",
  "W": "ddddda",
  "X": "ddddda",
  "Y": "ddddda",
  "Z": "ddddda",
  "AA": "ddddda",
  "AB": "dddda"
}
```

Comment: The `dataSource` doesn't match expected output.

Comment: at some point in your question there's something that totally scrambles the point and ends up with an expected output that totally doesn't make sense. I think you should better focus the main problem... are you just trying to convert a number to a different base using a map for the symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need an algorithm to convert numbers to an excel sheet column.
I believe this could be a solution.

```js
function convertToColumn(n){
    if (n == 0) return null;
    let result = '';
    while (n > 0) {
        let r = n % 26;
        let d = parseInt(n / 26);
        if (r == 0) {
            r = 26;
            d = d - 1;
        }
        result += String.fromCharCode (64 + r);
        n = d;
    }

    return result.split('').reverse().join("");
}

const dataSource =[{"column_name":"id"},{"column_name":"group_name"},{"column_name":"date_lol"},{"column_name":"aaaasdccc"},{"column_name":"created_table_at"},{"column_name":"test_bro"},{"column_name":"ddddd"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"},{"column_name":"ddddda"}]


const addKeyLetter = (data) => {
  const mapped = data.map((item, i) => ({
    [convertToColumn(i+1)]: item.column_name,
  }));
  const object = Object.assign({}, ...mapped);
 console.log(object);
};
addKeyLetter(dataSource);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method to convert from number to A-Z string, using base 26. However the result is a little different than your counting. Is this still something to consider?

```js
function convert_to_word(number) {
  var word = number.toString(26).split("").map(function(char) {
    var ascii = char.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)
    if (ascii <= 57) {
      ascii = ascii + 17
    } else {
      ascii = ascii + 10
    }
    return String.fromCharCode(ascii)
  }).join("")
  return word;
}

var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  result += convert_to_word(i) + " "
}
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```